# GWT CellTable header as a column

Tags: gwt, celltable

Is here a way to display the GWT CellTable header in the first column instead of the first row? This is because I have too many columns , and too lengthy a data and I believe they can be better displayed in this format:

```
|Header 01|And we will have the data for header 01 here|
|Header 02|And we will have the data for header 02 here|
|Header 03|And we will have the data for header 03 here|
|Header 04|And we will have the data for header 04 here|
|Header 05|And we will have the data for header 05 here|
|Header 06|And we will have the data for header 06 here|
|Header 07|And we will have the data for header 07 here|
|Header 08|And we will have the data for header 08 here|
|Header 09|And we will have the data for header 09 here|
|Header 10|And we will have the data for header 10 here|
|Header 11|And we will have the data for header 11 here|
|Header 12|And we will have the data for header 12 here|
|Header 13|And we will have the data for header 13 here|
|Header 14|And we will have the data for header 14 here|
|Header 15|And we will have the data for header 15 here|
```

I don't want to use FlexTable as I need editable cells which CellTable provides. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I do not think such kind of feature exists in gwt as per know. You can however implement your own custom widget to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom CellTableBuilder for doing this.
In the Showcase you can find an exemple http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid

```
  /**
   * Renders the data rows that display each contact in the table.
   */
  private class CustomTableBuilder extends AbstractCellTableBuilder<ContactInfo> {
    public CustomTableBuilder() {
      super(dataGrid);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void buildRowImpl(ContactInfo rowValue, int absRowIndex) {
      //Must be implemented
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you a bit more specific? What is `dataGrid` here? Your answer is not very clear.